# Selecting Tabs by id on jQuery UI 1.9+ with hidden tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, hidden

How to select a tab by id in recent versions of jQuery UI? I used to do this:

```
$(mytabs).tabs("select", "#tab_contents");
```

And it worked fine, even with some of the tabs hidden. Now I upgraded jQuery UI and the code above does not work anymore. I tried following some [other suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916955/520779) on this site, and ended up with this:

```
$(mytabs).tabs("option", "active", $(mytabs).find("li").index("#tab_header"));
```

Not only it's way more verbose, but it doesn't select the correct tab, since some of them are hidden. How can it be done?

P.S. To hide some tabs, I used `$("#tab_header").hide()`. Is this still correct in recent versions, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out a solution:

```
$(mytabs).tabs("option", "active", $("#tab_header").index());
```

This selects the correct tab, regardless of which ones are visible (it's even possible to select tabs currently invisible - the contents are shown, but the header is not).

Comment: A bit more dynamic: $("[href='#maintTab_" + id + "']").index()

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
       <li id="ha"><a href="#a">A</a></li>
       <li id="hb"><a href="#b">B</a></li>
       <li id="hc"><a href="#c">C</a></li>
       <li id="hd"><a href="#d">D</a></li>
       <li id="he"><a href="#e">E</a></li>
   </ul>
  <div id="a">AAA</div>
  <div id="b">BBB</div>
  <div id="c">CCC</div>
  <div id="d">DDD</div>
  <div id="e">EEE</div>
</div>
```

`.index` starts from `0`,

```
$(mytabs).tabs("option", "active", $("#ha").index());
```

but if you use `#a` instead of `#ha` use like this

```
$(mytabs).tabs("option", "active", $("#a").index()-1);
```

Comment: Where did you get that `index` starts from `1`? [The docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/y4r7N/) shows otherwise...

Comment: mgibsonbr, you are correct i was doing index on #div, instead of #li. And obviously #div is the second element and index starts from 1. My bad for not checking properly.

Comment: Ok, that explains it... :) However, your code only works if the order of the contents is consistent with the order of the headers. For the `tabs`, only the order of the headers matter. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/y4r7N/1/)