# Goto specific Tab (accordin) on # hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to switch tabs. But the problem is if i put the tabe id in url with #, it will not goto that specific tab.

```
<a href="index.php#tab2">Tab 2</a>
<a href="index.php#tab3">Tab 3</a>
```

Below is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

html code

```
        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a style="" href="#tab1">Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Jobs Posted</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4">Post A Job</a></li>
        </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
    </div>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
    </div>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab" style="padding-bottom:30px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add html for the elements you are trying to show. Preferably create a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You could implement jQuery UI and use the tabs() method as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578348/switch-to-selected-tab-by-name-in-jquery-ui-tabs hope this helps

Comment: you have to identify the elements that you show with id's - that is how the browser knows how to match the hash in the url to the element to scroll to.  You also need some jquery to read the url and show the appropiate element and to select the appropiate tab

Comment: i have added the html code too. @ekuusela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try modifying this line: `var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href').split("#")[1];`

with that your getting the `"tab2"` part of the link's `href` attribute

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var changeTab = function(id) {
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tab-content #' + id).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery('.tab-content #' + id + ':visible').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
    };

    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Here you will get the tab id, comming from the clicked hyperlink
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href').split("#")[1];
        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parents("li").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');
        changeTab(currentAttrValue);
    });
  
    var tab = document.location.href.split("#");
    if(tab.length > 0) {
      var id = tab[1];
      jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a[href="#' + id + '"]').click();
      window.addEventListener("load",function() {
        jQuery(window).scrollTop(0);
      },true);
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab1" class="tab active" style="padding-bottom:30px;">tab 1 content
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab" style="padding-bottom:30px;">tab 2 content
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab" style="padding-bottom:30px;">tab 3 content
</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs">
  
  <div class="tab-links">
    <a href="index.php#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <a href="index.php#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <a href="index.php#tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: well then your accordion has different structure, can you post your full accordion's html code?

Comment: but not working. Here is the web page http://inforge.in/ongoing-works/it-itech/client.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76569/discussion-between-gijo-varghese-and-santiago-hernandez).