# Bootstrap link to section/div/div

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying make a link from an `<a>` to a `<div>`, but I can't do this link. In the code your can see how the destination are inside a section/div/div/div/div/div/. When i do a link to a section i haven't problem, but in this case i can't do it. I'm using two styles from bootstrap.

I would do a link from `<a href="#tabmotora" ...>LEE MÁS</a>` to `<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabmotora"><section id="tabmotorasec"...>`. How can i do it?

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Solutions</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Plugin CSS -->
<link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="css2/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->

<link href="css2/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->

<link href="font-awesome/css2/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.html">Oiko Tec</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="about.html">Equipo</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="premios.html">Trayectoria</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Catálogo <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="productos.html">Productos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page-top">Servicios</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="serviciosadicionales.html">Servicios Adicional</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contacta</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



<section class="bg-primary" id="about" style="background-color:#FAAC58; padding: 0px;" class="clear_fix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Servicios
                        <!--<small>Equipo</small>-->
                    </h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="index.html"><b>Home</b></a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="active"><b>Servicios</b></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="texto-top" style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Servicios para huéspedes</h2>
                                    <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

            </div>

        </div>            
    </div>
</section>


<section id="tipos" class="bg-primary" style="background-color:#FAAC58; padding: 0px;" class="clear_fix">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#FAAC58; color:#000">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header" style="color:#FFF">Panel de Servicios</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-low-vision fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Discapacidad Visual</h4>
                        <p>Guía virtual interactivo para orientarte en las instalaciones hotel.</p>
                        <a href="#tabvisual" class="btn btn-default">LEE MÁS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-wheelchair fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>
                             <!-- <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-car fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>-->
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Discapacidad motora</h4>
                        <p>Control por voz de las instalaciones a través de tu smartphone.</p>
                        <a href="#tabmotora" class="btn btn-default" >LEE MÁS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-deaf fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Discapacidad Auditiva</h4>
                        <p>Sistema de seguridad por alertas en tu móvil y pulsera vibratoria.</p>
                        <a href="#tabauditiva" class="btn btn-default">LEE MÁS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="categorias" style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header">Tabs de servicios</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tabvisual" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-low-vision"></i> Discapacidad Visual</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#tabmotora" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i> Discapacidad Motora</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#tabauditiva" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-deaf"></i> Discapacidad auditiva</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tabvisual">
                        <h4></h4></br>
                                            <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabmotora"><section id="tabmotorasec" style="padding:0px; border: 0px; ">
                        <h4></h4></br>
                                            <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabauditiva">
                        <h4></h4></br>
                                            <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: what you want to link to what?

Comment: I edited my post, but i would link from button "LEE MAS" to "Discapacidad motora" tab, the visual aspect is like that: http://i67.tinypic.com/2nu5cm0.jpg

Comment: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578348/switch-to-selected-tab-by-name-in-jquery-ui-tabs)

Comment: Not exactly, I'm not using jquery, I'm just using html5 and bootstrap. Need I use jquery? I never used jquery.

Comment: yes, you will have to use it to toggle the ui tabs, that way you are interacting with bootstrap js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your link with adding **`data-toggle="tab"`** :

```
<a href="#tabmotora" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-default">LEE MÁS</a>
```

and add the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = this.href.split('#');
    $('.nav a').filter('a[href="#'+target[1]+'"]').tab('show');
})
</script>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.html">Oiko Tec</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="about.html">Equipo</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="premios.html">Trayectoria</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Catálogo <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="productos.html">Productos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page-top">Servicios</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="serviciosadicionales.html">Servicios Adicional</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contacta</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



<section class="bg-primary" id="about" style="background-color:#FAAC58; padding: 0px;" class="clear_fix">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Servicios
                        <!--<small>Equipo</small>-->
                    </h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="index.html"><b>Home</b></a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="active"><b>Servicios</b></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<section id="texto-top" style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Servicios para huéspedes</h2>
                                    <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

            </div>

        </div>            
    </div>
</section>


<section id="tipos" class="bg-primary" style="background-color:#FAAC58; padding: 0px;" class="clear_fix">
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#FAAC58; color:#000">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header" style="color:#FFF">Panel de Servicios</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-low-vision fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Discapacidad Visual</h4>
                        <p>Guía virtual interactivo para orientarte en las instalaciones hotel.</p>
                        <a href="#tabvisual" class="btn btn-default">LEE MÁS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-wheelchair fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>
                             <!-- <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-car fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>-->
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Discapacidad motora</h4>
                        <p>Control por voz de las instalaciones a través de tu smartphone.</p>
                        <a href="#tabmotora" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-default">LEE MÁS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                 <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary" style="color:#FFF"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-deaf fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="color:#D18A58"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4>Discapacidad Auditiva</h4>
                        <p>Sistema de seguridad por alertas en tu móvil y pulsera vibratoria.</p>
                        <a href="#tabauditiva" class="btn btn-default">LEE MÁS</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="categorias" style="padding: 30px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header">Tabs de servicios</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tabvisual" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-low-vision"></i> Discapacidad Visual</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#tabmotora" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i> Discapacidad Motora</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#tabauditiva" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-deaf"></i> Discapacidad auditiva</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tabvisual">
                        <h4></h4></br>
                                            <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabmotora"><section id="tabmotorasec" style="padding:0px; border: 0px; ">
                        <h4></h4></br>
                                            <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabauditiva">
                        <h4></h4></br>
                                            <p>...................................................................................................................</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = this.href.split('#');
    $('.nav a').filter('a[href="#'+target[1]+'"]').tab('show');
})
</script>
```

Comment: In the same way you can also add **`data-toggle="tab"`** to other links to do the same.

Comment: Now it works, thanks! But i have another problem now. The web page doesn't make autoscroll to div. When i press the button, the div change the content but it didn't do scroll to div, it remains in the button. I know I'm so dummy, sorry for that :(

Exists some script to simulate the click on the corresponding tab? Another problem exists with tab, the content is changed but the tab marked is the default tab.

Comment: @benpay try scrolling after showing the tab in the code. Keep trying if any problem mail me bsaraswat45@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you @Bhansa, now my web works fine thanks to you!!